# Overloaded function candidate matching problems

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, typeid

I'm not sure I understand the nuance of what is occurring here and was hoping for an explanation.

I'm calling several overloaded functions from a templated wrapper, `lapack_gesvd_nothrow`.  From there, I'm calling the individual fxns which are like this:

```
inline void lapack_gesvd(char *jobu, char *jobvt, 
  int *m, int *n, 
  float *a, int *lda,   
  float *s, 
  float *u, int *ldu,  
  float *vt, int *ldvt,
  float *work,  int *lwork, 
  int *info) {
  sgesvd_(jobu, jobvt, m, n, 
        a, lda, s, u, ldu, 
        vt, ldvt, work, lwork, 
        info);
}
inline void lapack_gesvd(char *jobu, char *jobvt, 
  int *m, int *n, 
  nm::Complex64 *a, int *lda,   
  nm::Complex64 *s, 
  nm::Complex64 *u, int *ldu,  
  nm::Complex64 *vt, int *ldvt,
  nm::Complex64 *work,  int *lwork, float *rwork,
  int *info) {
  cgesvd_(jobu, jobvt, m, n,
      a, lda, s, u, ldu,
      vt, ldvt, work, lwork,
      rwork, info);
}
```

It worked until I declared the second type of overloading (I'd overloaded with float and double, no problems) but now it throws a few errors and seems to not count my arguments well.

I call it from a function which took the arguments as:

```
template <typename DType, typename CType>
static int lapack_gesvd_nothrow(char *jobu, char *jobvt, 
  int m, int n, 
  void *a, int lda,   
  void *s, 
  void *u, int ldu,  
  void *vt, int ldvt,
  void *work,  int lwork,
  int info, void *rwork) {
....
DType* UPCASE = reinterpret_cast<DType*>(lowercase);
....

  if (typeid(DType) == typeid(CType)) {
    lapack_gesvd(jobu, jobvt, &m, &n, A, &lda, S, U, &ldu, VT, &ldvt, WORK, &lwork, &info);
  } else {
    CType* RWORK = reinterpret_cast<CType*>(rwork);
    lapack_gesvd(jobu, jobvt, &m, &n, A, &lda, S, U, &ldu, VT, &ldvt, WORK, &lwork, RWORK, &info);
  }
```

I literally only do the `reinterpret_casts` between the two.

Here is the fxn it is apparently looking for:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘lapack_gesvd(char*&, char*&, int*, int*, float*&, int*, float*&, float*&, int*, float*&, int*, float*&, int*, float*&, int*)
```

And here are the candidate matches:

```
candidates are:
note: void nm::math::lapack_gesvd(char*, char*, int*, int*, float*, int*, float*, float*, int*, float*, int*, float*, int*, int*) 
note:    candidate expects 14 arguments, 15 provided
void nm::math::lapack_gesvd(char*, char*, int*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*) 
note:   candidate expects 14 arguments, 15 provided
void nm::math::lapack_gesvd(char*, char*, int*, int*, nm::Complex64*, int*, nm::Complex64*, nm::Complex64*, int*, nm::Complex64*, int*, nm::Complex64*, int*, float*, int*)
note:   no known conversion for argument 5 from ‘float*’ to ‘nm::Complex64* {aka nm::Complex<float>*}’
```

I'm perplexed why the dereferencing shows up now, when it appears that it is required `error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'` without it, and required prior to this most recent overloading.

Your explanations and solutions would be most appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

It might come down to:

If I call `lapack_gesvd_nothrow<float, float>(...)` and then perform the typeid comparison `if (typeid(DType) == typeid(CType))`... will I get the expected answer?  Right now, it doesn't appear so.  How can I properly check template types for this comparison?

Comment: The function is waiting for nm::Complex64* but you are passing float*

Comment: Look at the first function definition.  That is the one that... 

1) takes 14 arguments
2) takes all `float*` instead of any `nm::Complex64*`

Comment: I assumed you wanted to call the 2nd function because you are passing 15 arguments. (note:   candidate expects 14 arguments, 15 provided)

Comment: Good point... I think you might have got this.  I suspect now that it is my comparison of `DType` to `CType`.  If I'm calling the 15 argument version with all floats, that is going wrong.  Perfect.

Comment: This suggests that my comparison should work... http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0100__Development/Comparethetypeidfortemplates.htm

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

You are doing this:

```
if (false) {
    // some language rule violation here
} else {
    // correct code here
}
```

Both sides of the if-else need to be compilable.

**Solution**

You can partially specialize the template.

```
template <class U, class V>
void foo(...){
    //assume U and V are different
}

template <class U>
void foo<U, U>(...){
    //assume both types are the same
}
```

**Why that happens**

The compiler substitute the type specified during compilation time. This way if you initialize with , it will change the if with float

```
lapack_gesvd_nothrow<float, float>(...)

if (typeid(float) == typeid(float))
```

This way, the code end up like this:

```
if (typeid(float) == typeid(float)){
    lapack_gesvd(jobu, jobvt, &m, &n, A, &lda, S, U, &ldu, VT, &ldvt, WORK, &lwork, &info);
} else {
    CType* RWORK = reinterpret_cast<CType*>(rwork);
    lapack_gesvd(jobu, jobvt, &m, &n, A, &lda, S, U, &ldu, VT, &ldvt, WORK, &lwork, RWORK, &info);
}
```

The compiler will see that the type of A is float. The first part of the if-else statement will be correct. Although, in the second part isnt. Here is an example of how the compiler will see it:

```
void foo(float, float){};
void foo(int, int, int){};
template <class U>(){
...
    U a, b, c;
    if (...)
        foo(a, b);
    else
        foo(a, b, c);
...
}
//Will be changed to
float a, b, c;
if (...)
    foo(a, b);
else
    foo(a, b, c);
```

Result in a compiler error in the else part, because theres no foo(float, float, float).

Comment: `typeid(double) == typeid(double)` should not be false.  Additionally, the code inside that was compiling and running prior to the templating.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler will change the CType for float. Afterwards will try to compile the code.

Comment: For you to see that `typeid(double) == typeid(double)` is not the problem, you can try changing the `if` to `if(true)` and see what happens.